# Position of subordinate clause with "obwohl" and "da"

Tags: conjunction, subordinate-clause

In written German, is it acceptable to place the subordinate clause after the main clause when you use *obwohl* and *da*?

> Ich komme heute Abend, obwohl ich krank bin.
>   (*vs* Obwohl ich krank bin, komme ich heute Abend.)
>
> Ich nehme meinen Regenschirm mit, da es regnet.
>   (*vs* Da es regnet, nehme ich meinen Regenschirm mit.)

Or is it "good" German always to place the subordinate clause first?

Answer (score 4):

Order of main and subordinate clause is entirely up to you. Both is correct, and both will be accepted - So no "good" or "bad" German here. The order *can* be used to put emphasis on certain parts of the sentence - General rule: Important things first.

If the thing you want to tell your friends is you'll be meeting with them tonight for a beer, put the hindrance you have to overcome in order to make it happen last.

If you want to emphasize how important they are for you, that, despite all odds, you want to meet them, put the subordinate clause first.

Answer (score -3):

surely it is correct both ways, but it just sound like a snob saying it this way (wanting to underline something)